# I am calling loop function every 1minute, set timeout is calling recursively after 1 and 2 loop call, why. function is calling twice to before call?

Tags: javascript

```
(
  function loop(){
      var rand=Math.round(Math.random()*100)*600;
   
      setTimeout(function(){

          mydialog();
      }, rand);
      console.log(rand)
      setInterval(loop, 60000);
  }()
                
);
```

Calling loop function after every one minute, please see below comment to understand my question please

Comment: caling loop function after every one minute. but while for after every one minute function mydialog(); is doubling to the previous calling. example: first min : mydialog()
         second min: mydialog()
                     mydialog()
         third min:  mydialog()
                     mydialog()
                     mydialog()
                     mydialog() this is how I am getting

Comment: setInterval(loop,60000) seems inside loop function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the code,Also the dialog function did not repeat. Below code for others reference as the code in your question seems to be broken.

```js
function mydialog(){
  console.log("dialog")
} 

function loop() {
    console.log("executed")
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) * 600;
    var c = 200
    setTimeout(function() {
        c = c + 1
        mydialog();
        
    }, rand);
    console.log({rand})
}
setInterval(loop, 60000);
```